# docker check for changes on mounted file system

Tags: docker, inotify

I wanted to make a ruby build environment within a docker container. Ruby is installed in the container and I can develop on my win10 host machine. I mount my host-working directory to the container and build the project. But now I thought about a little quality of life improvement: Wouldn't it be great if the container just listens on the mounted file system, and builds whenever I change something in my project?

After 5mins of google I found inotifywait which, at first sight, looked great, so I first tried it **without** mounting the filesystem:

```
[root@a3193720c4f1 testfolder]# inotifywait -m /tmp/testfolder/ -e modify -e create -e open |
>     while read path action file; do
>         echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
>     done
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
The file '' appeared in directory '/tmp/testfolder/' via 'OPEN,ISDIR'
The file 'newfile' appeared in directory '/tmp/testfolder/' via 'OPEN'
```

This worked out, but `/tmp/testfolder` is not the mounted directory, it's just a test-directory that I created in my container to get used to the inotifywait command. So this time I started my container and mounted the directory:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "D:\LokaleDaten\ELK_Docker\Docker\RVM\testfolder":"/tmp/testfolder" -w "/tmp/testfolder" myrvm
```

Then I started the inotifywait again, changed a file (on the host system which is mounted to the container), but the inotify didn't catch the changed file. I also checked if the file is changed in the container, and yes, the changes were made. 
So I am curious if I missed something, or is inotify not the right tool for that?

Kind regards, Manuel

Comment: I have used something similar [here](https://github.com/IvoNet/ivonet-docker-images/tree/master/databases/mysql) and it works fine. `inotifywait` should work, but it might be that Windows filesystem has different behaviour on file changes than linux does...

Comment: Well I think I might have found the problem 
http://blog.subjectify.us/miscellaneous/2017/04/24/docker-for-windows-watch-bindings.html
But using a python script doesn't work in my usecase.

Comment: I would rather have a tool that continously polls the filesystem in my container than on my host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the workaround listed [here](http://blog.subjectify.us/miscellaneous/2017/04/24/docker-for-windows-watch-bindings.html) requires you to install python, I kept searching. I then found a [solution](https://github.com/Angelinsky7/Docker-Volume-Watcher) where you don't have to install python, but that required to install a different tool on my host.

So basically what I ended up on is a self made script that just polls the filesystem every few seconds and checks the md5sum of the directory for changes. Here is the script if someone needs it (note: this is my first bash script that I ever made, so if something doesn't work or is bad practice, feel free to comment!):

```
#!/bin/sh
# script that gets a hash of a directory and checks every few seconds if the hash has changed
# if it has changed, it executes a command

if [ -d $1 ] || [ -f $1 ]; then
 f="$1"
else
 echo $(date +"%d.%m.%Y %T %:::z") ERROR: arg1 is neither a directory nor a file
 exit 1
fi

shift

if [ -z "$*" ]; then
 echo $(date +"%d.%m.%Y %T %:::z") ERROR: arg2 is required otherwise no command is executed
 exit 1
fi
cmd=$*

readonly getmd5sum="tar -cP $f | md5sum"
md5val="`eval ${getmd5sum}`"

while : ; do
 if [[ $md5val != `eval ${getmd5sum}` ]]; then
  md5val="`eval ${getmd5sum}`"
  $cmd
 fi
 sleep 2
done
```